# creating a matrix that holds pointers on its indexes

Tags: c

I am thinking about a way to create a matrix of pointers in C. Creating a matrix is easy as follow:

```
struct foo **m = malloc(n * sizeof *m);
//loop to alocate each column now
```

right?

But I don't need this. When I do `m[i][j]`, the pointer is dereferenced.

As I see, the only way to do this is having a structure to hold the pointer I need (because I have to access the same pointer from several indexes in `m`).

```
struct foo { struct bar *p; };
...
struct foo **m = ...
```

Is there any other solution for doing this?

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with the first approach.  You know you can just write `m[i]` to get a pointer, right?

Comment: yes, sure. but with m[i] i just have the line that holds the pointer i want. imagine that I need to store a pointer at `m[i][j]`. I can't simply do `m[i][j] = p;` because m[i][i] is ` struct foo` and not `struct foo *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution indeed is the second structure, although you can use a three star poitner `struct foo ***`, it's normally not a good solution, since you can always have `struct`s to give more *structure* to your data, and make your code less error prone.

Answer (score -1):

```
struct foo **m = malloc(n * sizeof *m);
```

This code creates a variable `m`, which is a pointer of pointer to `struct foo`. So if you dereference it twice, you now just have a `struct foo`. Looks like you want a pointer to pointer to pointer of `struct foo`--in other words, `struct foo ***m`.

Comment: A `***` pointer in this scenario is a really bad idea, there is something missing in the question, but I would guess that the best solution would be another structure.

Comment: Didn't know that the construct `struct foo ***` was possible in C. why it's bad, @iharob?

Comment: @LuizEduardoF. `struct foo ****` is possible, but do not do that, you really don't want to become [a three star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Comment: @LuizEduardoF. just read the link, it's not simple to explain how many things can go wrong when you use a `***` pointer, the only situation I do use a `***` pointer is when I want to pass the address of a `**` pointer. Using a `***` pointer, is in itself a challenge.

Comment: The link doesn't actually say much about *why* using triple indirection is bad. Personally, I'd rather have direct triple indirection that double indirection and a superfluous struct or typedef.

Comment: @jangler You are then the dangerous three star pointer! It's not a bad thing, it's just that it makes your code some messy so difficult to maintain that it's not worth it, your data _structure_ will be clearer if you use the `struct`. I am not saying that you should never use that either, sometimes it could be useful, but I don't think this situation is one of them.